# Domain of a composite function $g(h(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

Say we have $g(x)=x-5$ and $h(x)=x^2+4x+6$. Say we have to find the composite function $g(h(x))$ and then find the domain of that function. I know that $g(h(x))=x^2+4x+1$. Now, if I had to consider the function $x^2+4x+1$ on its own and not as a composite of two other function then I can easily say that its domain is $(-\infty, \infty)$. However, I'm not sure of the domain of the composite function $g(h(x))$ would be the same since $h(x)$ has range $[2, \infty)$ and the values of $h(x)$ are the inputs of the composite function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is indeed $\Bbb R$. You can still put any value of $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ into $g(h(x))$. The fact that $h$ has range $[2,\infty)$ will simply only affect the range of $g\circ h$. The range of $h$ does not affect the domain of $g\circ h$ in this case because $g$ has domain $\Bbb R$.

If $g$ were a function with domain $[3,\infty)$ for example, then the domain of $g\circ h$ would need to change, because $h(x)\in [2,\infty)$ if $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$. For instance, if $x=-2$ then $h(x)=2$, and then $g(h(x))=g(2)$ is undefined.

In general, if $f:X\subseteq \Bbb R\to Y\subseteq \Bbb R$ and $g:U\subseteq \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, then we can compose $g\circ f$ if $Y\subseteq U$.

Comment: So in the scenario you mentioned the domain of $g \circ h$ would need to be changed to a subset of the domain of $h$ s.t. the range of h is equal to the domain of $g$?

Comment: It wouldn't have to be equal, but certainly the domain of $g \circ h$ would need to be changed so that the range of $h$ is contained in the domain of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the domain of any composite function using the following formula
$$
D_{f\circ g} = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&x\in D_g\\
&g(x)\in D_f
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
In your example
$
g(x)=x+5,D_g=\mathbb R
$
and
$
h(x)=x^2+4x+6,D_h=\mathbb R
$
then the domain of the composite function will be
$$
D_{g\circ h} = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&x\in D_h\\
&h(x)\in D_g
\end{aligned}
\right.
=
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&x\in \mathbb R\\
&x^2+4x+6\in \mathbb R
\end{aligned}
\right.
=
\mathbb R
$$
so
$
(g\circ h)(x)=g(h(x))=x^2+4x+1
$